# does self-signing a certificate for an Android Mobile App cause the publisher to show as UNKNOWN?

Tags: android, code-signing, digital-certificate, certificate-authority

Android requires Mobile Apps to be digitally signed with a certificate and there are 2 ways - (1) Self-signing the certificates and (2) Getting a signed certificate by a 3rd party certificate authority. [This link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html) says, "When using a self-signed certificate, the application pubilsher will show up as UNKNOWN."
Is that true and if it is, where does the 'UNKNOWN' publisher show up in the app or anywhere else? Are there any other confirmation pop-ups that the user has to confirm if the app is self-signed?

Thanks,
Sumanth.

Answer (score 0):

There are no warnings or pop up dialogs for self signed certificates.  The unknown doesn't show up anywhere for all I know. I just wonder why that sight would say that. According to Google, it doesn't do anything.

Cited from: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I am beginning on this stuff to, so I may not be the best source. One noob to another, good luck!